# Puppet stdlib "range()" is not working as expected

Tags: ruby, node.js, puppet

According to the Puppet stdlib docs, range() is supposed to return an array of values. However, it does not appear to be working properly:

```
class rangetest {

  $r1 = range(1,5)
  $r2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

  if $r1 == $r2 {

    notify { "same" : }

  } else {

    notify { "not same" : }

  }

}
```

The result of the above test returns "not same". What I am actually trying to do is use the function, difference(), which takes 2 arrays as arguments but when I try this:

```
difference($r1,$r2) - assuming $r1 and $r2 have values from the above example
```

it returns: difference(): Requires 2 arrays).

Comment: What version of Puppet are you using?

Comment: I'm on puppet version, 3.7.1

Comment: I fail to reproduce with `3.7.1` and stdlib `4.3.2`. `$ puppet apply -e '$r = range(1,5) $s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] $d = difference($r, $s) notice($d)'` yields `Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 1 2 3 4 5`. Granted, this does not appear to be the actual difference, but it doesn't fail in a weird way either.